# How to use XLink data types in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xlink

When I try to run XSD file with xjc I get this error:

> Error resolving component 'xlin:href'. It was detected that
>   'xlin:href' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org', but components from
>   this namespace are not referenceable from schema document "file
>   address" perhaps the prefix of 'xlin:href' needs to be changed. If
>   this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should
>   be added to "file address"

Below is the code:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="properties">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="property" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="giataId" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:dateTime" name="lastUpdate" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xlin:href" xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="lastUpdate"/>
     </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access any XSD components in another namespace, you have import that namespace.

In your case, add

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
           schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd"/>
```

to your XSD to have access to the XLink components.

---

Here is general guidance for referencing XLink components such as `href` from an XSD:

1. Declare `xlink` namespace prefix, commonly on the `xs:schema` element:

   ```
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   ```
2. Import the XLink XSD:

   ```
   <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
              schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd"/>
   ```
3. Reference the needed XLink component:

   ```
   <xs:attribute ref="xlink:href" xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
   ```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but still I dont know exactly what to do as this is my first experience in generating xml codes could you guid me more plz about where should I declare xlink name space and import the xlink xsd I dont know where tu put these @kjhughes

Comment: It appears that you have everything in place except the `xs:import`, which should be added as a child of `xs:schema`, typically as one of the first children before its use by other siblings.